# Does C++ optimisation level affect Swig Python module performance

Tags: c++, python, optimization, g++, swig

I have a large Swig Python module. The C++ wrapper ends up being about 320,000 LoC (including headers I guess). I currently compile this with -O1, and g++ produces a binary that is 44MiB in size, and takes about 3 minutes to compile it.

If I turn off optimisation (-O0), the binary comes out at 40MiB, and it takes 44s to compile.

Is compiling the wrapper with -O0 going to hurt the performance of the python module significantly? Before I go and profile the performance of the module at different optimisation levels, has anyone done this sort of analysis before or have any insight into whether it matters?

Answer (score 3):

-O0 deactivates all the optimizations performed by gcc. And optimizations matter.

So, without a lot of knowledge in your application, I could suggest that this will hurt the performance of your application.

A usually safe optimization level to use is -O2.

You can check the kind of optimizations performed by GCC in:
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html.

But at the end, if you want to know exactly you should compile at different levels and profile.

Comment: Thanks, I understand this. 

I wanted to know if anyone had any specific experience with Swig wrapper optimisation. A Google search not show anything published.

Answer (score 2):

This is bad irrespective of SWIG modules or not. There are *many* optimisations that happen even with `gcc -O1` which you will miss if you prevent them happening.

You can check the difference by inspecting the asm generated by your compiler of choice. Of these the ones I trivially know will be detrimental to SWIG's generated wrapper:

1. Dead code elimination:

   ```
   void foo() {
     int a = 1;
     a = 0;
   }
   ```

   With -O1 this entirely pointless code gets totally removed:

   ```
   foo:
           pushl   %ebp
           movl    %esp, %ebp
           popl    %ebp
           ret
   ```

   whereas with -O0 it becomes:

   ```
   foo:
           pushl   %ebp
           movl    %esp, %ebp
           subl    $16, %esp
           movl    $1, -4(%ebp)
           movl    $0, -4(%ebp)
           leave
           ret
   ```
2. Register allocation will be detrimentally impacted in functions with lots of local variables - most SWIG wrapper functions will see a hit from this. It's hard to show a concise example of this though.
3. Another example, the output from gcc compiling the SWIG wrapper for the prototype:

   ```
   int foo(unsigned int a, unsigned int b, unsigned int c,  unsigned int d);
   ```

   Generates with `-O0`:

   ```
   Java_testJNI_foo:
           pushl   %ebp
           movl    %esp, %ebp
           subl    $88, %esp
           movl    16(%ebp), %eax
           movl    %eax, -48(%ebp)
           movl    20(%ebp), %eax
           movl    %eax, -44(%ebp)
           movl    24(%ebp), %eax
           movl    %eax, -56(%ebp)
           movl    28(%ebp), %eax
           movl    %eax, -52(%ebp)
           movl    32(%ebp), %eax
           movl    %eax, -64(%ebp)
           movl    36(%ebp), %eax
           movl    %eax, -60(%ebp)
           movl    40(%ebp), %eax
           movl    %eax, -72(%ebp)
           movl    44(%ebp), %eax
           movl    %eax, -68(%ebp)
           movl    $0, -32(%ebp)
           movl    -48(%ebp), %eax
           movl    %eax, -28(%ebp)
           movl    -56(%ebp), %eax
           movl    %eax, -24(%ebp)
           movl    -64(%ebp), %eax
           movl    %eax, -20(%ebp)
           movl    -72(%ebp), %eax
           movl    %eax, -16(%ebp)
           movl    -16(%ebp), %eax
           movl    %eax, 12(%esp)
           movl    -20(%ebp), %eax
           movl    %eax, 8(%esp)
           movl    -24(%ebp), %eax
           movl    %eax, 4(%esp)
           movl    -28(%ebp), %eax
           movl    %eax, (%esp)
           call    foo
           movl    %eax, -12(%ebp)
           movl    -12(%ebp), %eax
           movl    %eax, -32(%ebp)
           movl    -32(%ebp), %eax
           leave
           ret
   ```

   Compared to `-O1` which generates just:

   ```
   Java_testJNI_foo:
           pushl   %ebp
           movl    %esp, %ebp
           subl    $24, %esp
           movl    40(%ebp), %eax
           movl    %eax, 12(%esp)
           movl    32(%ebp), %eax
           movl    %eax, 8(%esp)
           movl    24(%ebp), %eax
           movl    %eax, 4(%esp)
           movl    16(%ebp), %eax
           movl    %eax, (%esp)
           call    foo
           leave
           ret
   ```
4. With `-O1` g++ can generate far smarter code for:

   ```
   %module test

   %{
   int value() { return 100; }
   %}

   %feature("compactdefaultargs") foo;

   %inline %{
     int foo(int a=value(), int b=value(), int c=value()) {
       return 0;
     }
   %}
   ```

The short answer is with optimisations disabled completely GCC generates extremely naive code - this is true of SWIG wrappers as much as any other program, if not more given the style of the automatically generated code.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I'm still confused as to why -O0 produced a smaller binary than -O1. I will inspect the generated code a bit more closely and report back.